# How to read parquet file from s3 using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to read the parquet file which is in s3 using pandas.

Below is the code

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd



key = 'key'
secret = 'secret'
s3_client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id = key,
    aws_secret_access_key = secret,
    region_name = 'region_name'
)
print(s3_client)

AWS_S3_BUCKET='bucket_name'
filePath='data/wine_dataset'

response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=AWS_S3_BUCKET, Key=filePath)

status = response.get("ResponseMetadata", {}).get("HTTPStatusCode")

if status == 200:
    print(f"Successful S3 get_object response. Status - {status}")
    books_df = pd.read_parquet(response.get("Body"))
    print(books_df)
else:
    print(f"Unsuccessful S3 get_object response. Status - {status}")
```

I am getting the below error

```
NoSuchKey: An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: The specified key does not exist.
```

But when I read the same s3 path using pyspark it worked

```
path= 's3a://bucket_name/data/wine_dataset'

df = spark.read.parquet(path)
```

I am not sure why it is not working using pandas. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: what does the response look like?

Comment: See if this helps: [The S3 client provided by Amazon EMR are not from the Apache](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#Warning_5:_The_S3_client_provided_by_Amazon_EMR_are_not_from_the_Apache)

Comment: Can you try with "s3n://bucket_name/data/wine_dataset"?

Comment: I can't use s3n because I am using boto3 object to read the data just by using bucket and  file names

Comment: @JoshFriedlander this is the reponse: "NoSuchKey: An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: The specified key does not exist.
"

Comment: no, I meant print the response - is the Body actually a path to a parquet file?

Comment: @JoshFriedlander it is failing at get_object line "response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=AWS_S3_BUCKET, Key=filePath)"